# performance issues when web-scraping real-time data using javascript and python flask webserver

Tags: javascript, python, performance, flask, web-scraping

I am extracting continuously updating data from an html tag using javascript in the chrome developer tools console and sending it to a webserver (python flask) to be able to further process the data within a python application.
The problem is that 50% of the time, the request takes less than 5 ms, BUT the other 50% of the time the request takes around 300ms which is too much as the application I intend to build is latency sensitive.

How can I reduce the time required for ALL html POST requests down to less than 5ms?

The javascript code used in chrome is:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:5000/mqtt/", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
console.log(Date.now());
xhr.send(Date.now().toString());
```

The python code (python 3.6) is:

```
import time
from flask import request, Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

application = Flask(__name__)
CORS(application)


@application.route('/mqtt/', methods=['POST'], strict_slashes=False)
def process_prices():
    start = time.time()
    data = request.get_data().decode("utf-8")
    time_decoding = time.time()

    print('timestamp javascript', data)
    print('timestamp python', time.time()*1000)

    print('total time: ', int((time.time()-start)*1000))
    print('decoding time: ', int((time_decoding - start) * 1000))

    return "OK"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(debug=False)
```

Results: 
When I execute the javascript code the first time, the difference between the timestamp collected in the javascript code and the timestamp measured in python is around 300ms. If I run the same javascript code again within 10 seconds from running it the first time, the time difference is reduced to less than 5 ms. If I wait 10-11 seconds for the code to run the second time, the code again takes 300ms. if I keep re-executing the javascript code repeatedly every 2-3 seconds, every second time the request takes 300ms to be picked up by the server and every other time it only takes 1-5 ms. 
This makes me think that either chrome or the flask server are somehow being configured in a way that adds additional latency and that it should be possible to reduce the time required for ALL requests to get to the webserver down to less than 5 ms rather than only half of them.

Output from flask webserver:

```
timestamp javascript 1555342312986
timestamp python 1555342313289.659
total time:  1
decoding time:  0
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Apr/2019 17:31:53] "POST /mqtt/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
timestamp javascript 1555342314901
timestamp python 1555342314903.6602
total time:  0
decoding time:  0
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Apr/2019 17:31:54] "POST /mqtt/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
timestamp javascript 1555342315912
timestamp python 1555342316217.7195
total time:  1
decoding time:  0
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Apr/2019 17:31:56] "POST /mqtt/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: Switch to websocket or something that does http2 maybe. Why did you tag this with web-scraping?

Comment: @pguardiario: tagged as web-scraping, because the idea is to extract continuously updating price data from some websites comparable to yahoo finance that don't have a documented API. I have very little knowledge about how to set up an alternative communication system between these websites and a python application. Would you know how I can run a more complex javascript code that does websocket/http2 from a browser console and what package/library I could use in python that serves as an endpoint?

Comment: If you really need low latency then websockets is the way to go. I don't know of any python libraries that do http2, it seems like nodejs would be a better bet.